# can I call my callback function from opengl's display

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, opengl, callback

I am trying to call a callback function from

```
 void display(void){

    my_draw(&here_is_the_actual_drawing);

 }

 void here_is_the_actual_drawing(){

    glVertex2f(x,y);

 }
```

in main the opengl loop call display .. like

```
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
```

My question is can we do this ?? I tried in my code it compiles but gets stuck .. [ my_draw will create a thread that will call here_is_the_actual_drawing ---- ok so no threads just call back ]

Comment: First of all, you cannot draw in OpenGL using threads (in general, that is).

Comment: yes Jonas u are right.. so lets say  I dont use thread but want just to call the call back function from the display ..

Comment: That should work without problems. Can you show the code of ``my_draw``?

Comment: Also whats the rest of: here_is_the_actual_drawing?

Comment: About how to draw multithreading take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742090/how-to-draw-opengl-graphics-from-different-threads

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Of course you can use OpenGL from multiple threads. It's just an awful lot of work to get it work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my_draw will create a thread that will call here_is_the_actual_drawing ---- ok so no threads just call back ]

You can not simply *just* call OpenGL commands from any thread. OpenGL needs a context, and each OpenGL context can be active in only one thread at a time. It is perfectly possible to migrate a context between threads. However this requires that you have full control over context creation and management.

By using a simple framework like (Free)GLUT, GLFW or SDL you do not have control over context management. But technically it is possible.

But not everything whats possible makes sense. Usually keeping all OpenGL operations to a single thread, to be precise the main GUI thread, is the best solution. Multithreaded OpenGL is usefull in only a very small number of situations, and even then only with very limited circumstances.

BTDT (actually my current project makes heavy use of multithreaded OpenGL)