# java RuntimeException in slick2D game project

Tags: java, slick2d

I have created a new thread in a project having this code :

```
battleStart = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(compteur<50){
                BattleStart.draw(0,0);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                compteur++;
            }
        }
    });
```

but i got this exception : ***Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.***
What should I do to fix such an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't. Multi-threading ([see this thread](http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2982)) is not supported.

You might find a way around it with a lot of custom code (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742090/how-to-draw-opengl-graphics-from-different-threads) and [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading)), but you should first reconsider your design. Is it really necessary to run this code in its own thread? Because it seems like a really bad idea to draw on the same context from different threads and I cannot really think of a situation where I would want to do that (it does not improve performance and makes the code harder to read and maintain).

Comment: thx for comment but i think i really need to draw some graphics in a different thread because i need some parallel drawings ...

Comment: Tim is correct, especially if you're using slick. There should be no need to create extra threads, as games are step based. It wouldn't make sense, even if you are trying to draw two things at the same time. In your update method, you would do the necessary logic, then in your render method, draw any images with your updated data. Frame by frame.

Comment: And on a second note, I believe what you are trying to accomplish (based on the way your code looks) involves time stepping, which you can utilize the update delta time and sum over frames per update interval; once a specific number is reached after adding up delta times over time, you can have an if statement that triggers.

Comment: @user3578325 No you don't. Drawing doesn't work that way. Everything you draw in your `render()` method gets drawn together at the end.